# What is the meaning of the warnings when using module after workspace()?

Tags: import, module, warnings, julia, using

Following situation:

```
using PyPlot
workspace()
using PyPlot
```

This prints a gush of warnings. All about overwriting method definitions. Same for (all) other modules.

I thought `workspace()` would generate a new, clean `Main` module without any definitions remaining (except for those in `LastMain`).

Why the warnings?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what your warnings are. In my Julia, The warnings are new method definations and deprecated warnings. So workspace() can't take affects on them.